# python equivalents to Meteorserver or Derbyjs or Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, python, web-frameworks, serverside-javascript

are there any python frameworks that is akin to meteorserver, derbyjs, angularjs? basically something like pyjs but with support for UI data binding witnessed in knockoutjs, and angularjs with a single model base to instantly update the UI (meteorserver, derbyjs)?

Answer (score -1):

If you've got a pile of money, there's [Planet](http://www.planetframework.com/).